# About 3D Ising model

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ising-model, lattice-model

In the 2D Ising model, Onsager provided an exact solution for the lattice model in 1944. However, despite numerous efforts, exact solutions for higher-dimensional Ising models have yet to be derived.

Nonetheless, over the past decades, significant progress has been made using numerical analysis and conformal bootstrap techniques to calculate critical exponents with unparalleled accuracy. By comparing the resulting bounds on operator dimensions and OPE (Operator Product Expansion) coefficients in 3D with known results, it has been discovered that the 3D Ising model occupies a unique position at a corner point on the boundary of the allowed parameter space. This finding raises intriguing questions:

Does the recent intensive analysis of the 3D Ising model reveal intrinsic differences between the 2D and 3D Ising models?

Does this analysis unveil the reason why the 3D Ising model holds a special place within the space of 3D conformal field theories?

Comment: Do we know where the 2D Ising model would occupy if we also perform a numerical bootstrap analysis in $d=2$?

Comment: @MengCheng similar: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2211 section 4.1 (interestingly no kinks at higher minimal models)

Comment: @NiharKarve thanks, so it looks like there is no intrinsic difference between 2D and 3D...